# RenderShrinkWrappingViewport does not support returning intrinsic dimensions

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

I want a text button when on click shows a simpleDialog vith a listView.builder but I don't know how to code it. I always have an error.
Can you help me?

Here is my code:

```dart
TextButton(
    child: const Text('Selet instruments needed'),
    onPressed: () {
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) => SimpleDialog(
                  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                  title: const Text('Select instruments needed'),
                  children: [
                    ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: 2,
                        itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                          return ListTile(
                              title: instrumentType[index]['name'],
                              onTap: () {});
                        }))
                  ]));
    })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap your `ListView` with `SizedBox` widget and using `LayoutBuilder` help to get the constraints

```dart
  TextButton(
        child: const Text('Selet instruments needed'),
        onPressed: () {
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) => LayoutBuilder(
              builder: (context, constraints) => SimpleDialog(
                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                title: const Text('Select instruments needed'),
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: constraints.maxHeight * .7, // 70% height
                    width: constraints.maxWidth * .9,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      itemCount: 44,
                      itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                        return ListTile(onTap: () {});
                      }),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        })
```

Comment: Glad to help, if you use `AlertDialog` you can have scrollable parameter, and you can just use `Column` there.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
void _show(BuildContext ctx) {
    showDialog(
      context: ctx,
      builder: (_) {
        return SimpleDialog(
          title: const Text('The Title'),
          children: [
            SimpleDialogOption(
              child: const Text('Option 1'),
              onPressed: () {
                // Do something
                print('You have selected the option 1');
                Navigator.of(ctx).pop();
              },
            ),
            SimpleDialogOption(
              child: const Text('Option 2'),
              onPressed: () {
                // Do something
                print('You have selected the option 2');
                Navigator.of(ctx).pop();
              },
            )
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Call Dialog function :

```
TextButton(
          child: const Text('Show The Simple Dialog'),
          onPressed: () => _show(context),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

- Came across this issue when trying to add a Stepper() inside a Dialog.
- Since stepper behaves like a ListView, the problem is the same.
- Simple solution is to wrap the the Stepper (or ListView) inside a SizedBox.
- Figuring out the right width and height for all possible devices is not feasible, so we can use `width: double.maxFinite` and height `height: double.maxFinite` which will let Flutter figure it out.

  ```
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text("Test"),
        context: SizedBox(
          width: double.maxFinite,
          height: double.maxFinite,
          child: Stepper(
            currentStep: x, // your stepper index
            steps: [
              Step(...),
              Step(...),
            ],
            .... // Other Stepper properties
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  );
  ```